# Adding a dependency to maven (link is with a port)

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I'm having a problem adding a dependency to my maven project.
The link to the .jar is here -> http://maven.etherfirma.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/jHipchat/0.0.1/

I already tried this:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maven.etherfirma</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-content-repositories-public-com-github-jHipchat</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But that didnt work at all.

I hope someone can help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Using the Internal Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#Using_the_Internal_Repository).

> Using the internal repository is quite simple. Simply make a change to add a **repositories** element

Add local repository to `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>etherfirma</id>
    <url>http://maven.etherfirma.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

And correct your [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>jHipchat</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Coordinates of your artifact jHipchat are available in [jHipchat-0.0.1.pom](http://maven.etherfirma.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/jHipchat/0.0.1/jHipchat-0.0.1.pom)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new repository, like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>etherfirma</id>
      <url>http://maven.etherfirma.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

And your dependency should look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>jHipchat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```